# Emacs on a Mac (short) keyboard: how does one make the Command and Control equivalent?

Tags: emacs

The recent MacBook Pro keyboard and the bluetooth keyboard layout has only one Control key but two Command keys.  And symmetric keys at that.  For a while I attempted to remap the modifier keys using the System preferences which works OK for me but drives anyone else using my computers crazy.  This got me to wondering, is there a simpler way to achieve equivalence between Control (C-) and Command (S-) other than rebinding all the existing S-* keybindings?

To be clear, I am looking to have the keys labeled "command" execute as a Ctrl- prefix while I do not care what the key labeled "control" does, i.e. having three Control keys is OK.

Comment: I generally map Caps Lock to Control. Try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set mac-command-modifier,

> mac-command-modifier is a variable defined in `ns-win.el'.
> Its value is super
>
> This variable is an alias for `ns-command-modifier'.
>
> Documentation:
> This variable describes the behavior of the command key.
> Set to control, meta, alt, super, or hyper means it is taken to be that key.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you try mapping Caps Lock to Control instead, and keeping Command as Meta.  Otherwise you don't have any modifiers left to use as Meta, other than the rather awkward Option (which is pretty useful for typing special characters, anyway).

If you're really set on making Command into Control, you can use [KeyRemap4Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) to set up an application-specific keyboard remapping.

Comment: emacs can remap control key natively no need for any third party software see my answer.

Comment: Gah, always forget about that.  Anyway, KeyRemap4Macbook will work in the general case.

Comment: While Hanza's answer is a little better, the reference to KeyRemap4Macbook is much appreciated.